# Error when running this piece of code. What is root and how to find it?

Tags: python, rdkit

Tried to install a dataset:

```
import rdkit
from torch_geometric.datasets import MoleculeNet
 
# Load the ESOL dataset
data = MoleculeNet(root=".", name="ESOL")
data
```

And an error occured:

```
RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed locating file data.pkl: file not found
```

Cannot fix it, i dunno what 'root' is. Running on Windows in Colab btw

Tried to fix the problem by imstalling the identical dataset by uploading csv file but later this variant was useless because it belongs to another class.

UPD: checked the uploaded files and there was "esol" folder. Perhaps dataset has been installed but the "data" variable is not defined.

UPD1: tried to fix the code:

```
data = MoleculeNet(root=r"[file path]", name="ESOL")
```

And the same error shows(

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.datasets.MoleculeNet.html?highlight=MoleculeNet#torch_geometric.datasets.MoleculeNet)?

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I tried, didn't help much, i don't know where and how to find root directory

Comment: The root directory is whichever folder you saved your dataset in.

Comment: And acts like any other file path in python: make it an absolute path if you need _true_ control over where files at read/written, otherwise it'll be a path relative to the dir you're running python in, which you can verify by printing the result of [getcwd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Comment: Thanks, figured out what root directory is. The problem is still here though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem wasn't in this piece of code. I restarted my notebook and installed modules as following:

```
import torch
!pip install torch_geometric
!pip install rdkit
```

Then tried to download that dataset, and it worked! In the previous version i took some lines of code from the guide, and the installation method was way more complex, maybe this caused an error.